# iPhoto claims there is an update available

Tags: macos, photos.app, software-update, photo-stream

iPhoto came with my Mac. It is currently version 9.1.1.

When I open iPhoto, it pops up:

"An iPhoto update is available. Would you like to open Software Update?"

Then it offers me to start Software Update, but it finds no updates. Some people said I should check in the AppStore, but it asks me to pay if I want to take iPhoto from there.

I am running Mac OS X 10.7.2

I believe this update is to enable Photo Stream.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you moved or renamed iPhoto?

Comment: aha - that is a possibility indeed

Comment: You are right, I moved it back and now Software Updates says there is an update. This is linked to this question I posted a while ago: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/19428/creating-folders-in-the-applications-folder